# Oracle: REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract desired string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string format of `MID: 124281-2 - SID: 31701` in a column.

Need to extract `124281-2` and `31701` from it.

Have tried

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('MID: 124281-2 - SID: 31701', ':[^,]+-') FROM DUAL;
```

But the result is `: 124281-2 -`

How can I remove the `:` and `-`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `select regexp_substr(mid_sid_column, '\d[0-9-]*', 1, 1) as mid, regexp_substr(mid_sid_column, '\d[0-9-]*', 1, 2) as sid from table`

Answer (score 0):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. -- Jamie Zawinski

That's not to say never use regex, but in a case like this there may be a much simpler option; could you try using a simpler approach - say, SUBSTR characters 6 to 13 (124281-2) and characters 22 to 26 (31701)? That's assuming fixed substring lengths, which you may not have - but it's worth looking at.

Alternatively, if you have to use a regex, you'll need to use groups to trap the two values you want back; try being more specific - something like `[A-Z]+: ([0-9\-]+) \- [A-Z]+: ([0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

from :

> 'MID: 124281-2 - SID: 31701'

the regex to get 124281-2 only is:

```
[0-9]{1,6}-[0-9]
```

description:

```
[0-9]{1,6} match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: Between 1 and 6 times, as many times as possible, giving back as
                needed.
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- matches the character - literally
[0-9] match a single character present in the list below
```

if the restriction for the wanted characters is between ': ' and ' -' the you can use the following regex:

```
(?<=:\s)[^,]+(?=\s-)
```

description:

```
    (?<=:\s) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        : matches the character : literally
        \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    [^,]+ match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
                    giving back as needed.
        , the literal character ,
    (?=\s-) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        - matches the character - literally
```

hope this helps.